# Что именно идентифицирует посетителя сайта?

Tags: сервер, логика, backend

Изучая backend, столкнулся с такой проблемой недопонимания:  есть сайт, сервер *Nodejs* (в принципе, какой угодно, но меня интересует именно *Nodejs*) и зашел на сайт посетитель. Не важно есть ли регистрация на сайте или нет — что именно идентифицирует посетителя?

Я знаю, что управляется это сессиями. Читал [тут](https://nodejsdev.ru/doc/sessions/), но не понял откуда именно и чего и с каких данных server понимает, что вот сейчас именно тот самый посетитель? Допустим, на сайт зашли два посетителя: один из Москвы  другой из Воркуты и на сайте есть чат. Чат простой и банальный - можно без регистрации отправить какой-нибудь пост или поболтать. Надо в чате сделать так, чтобы сообщение пользователя из Воркуты было на синем фоне, а сообщения из Москвы — на  зеленом. Тут же на этот сайт зашел новый посетитель тоже из Москвы и с того же IP адреса, но с другого компа который в соседней комнате нашего москвича (допустим это его супруга), вот ее (супруги) сообщение должен иметь фон оранжевый...

В итоге, не прошу никакого кода (если это только не обязательно для наглядного примера). Прошу объяснить саму логику восприятия сервером посетителей. Как определить кто есть кто?

Comment: Случайным образом сгенерированная строка в cookies. Всё.

Comment: @andreymal, только не ругайся))) а если куки не использовать или это не возможно? это процесс  по умолчанию?

Comment: Сервер проверяет есть ли у посетителя кукис, и если нет, то выдает ему уникальный ключ в качестве кукиса, тот его запоминает и показывает при каждом запросе, и сервер тоже запоминает себе. А потом сверяет. IP может вообще никак не участвовать.

Comment: Без куков можно в принципе использовать localStorage через JS... Но по сути будет то же самое.

Comment: @Air ну тогда что угодно, куда можно запихнуть случайную строку и где она не потеряется. В старые времена, когда куки работали не очень, эту случайную строку пихали прямо в адрес (по-моему php даже до сих пор умеет так делать). Но пихать куда-то помимо кук смысла обычно нету

Comment: Настолько все банально получается? почти  зная ответ задаю вопрос?

Comment: @Air в последнее время начинают выпендриваться, вместо случайной строки используя что-то типа JWT или в случае SPA пихая всё это дела в HTTP-заголовки вместо кук, но лично я считаю всё это бессмысленным для большинства сайтов)

Comment: @andreymal, получается при новой сессии, а могу сгенерировать некий ключ временный, присвоить его посетителю, отправить ему это дело в куки и таким образом контролировать его?

Comment: @Air типа того. Только, разумеется, пользователь может все ключи почистить и захотеть получить новые, но тут уж ничего не поделать, и это стоит учитывать в некоторых вопросах безопасности

Comment: @andreymal, это понятно, в принципе это и надо, благодарю за участие, все содержательно...  И еще напиши подробности ответом, думаю будет полезнее на будущее... Не хочу сам, потому что ты лучше ответишь, наверняка там есть подводные камни, о которых я точно пока не могу знать...

Comment: @koshkashoshka, благодарю за участие... Было  содержательно...

Comment: Думаю, стоит убрать тэги `php` и `node.js`, ибо вопрос по факту к ним не привязан. А у людей (вроде меня) какой-то из них и вовсе может стоять в игнорируемых, что приведёт к пропуску такого интересного топика

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, тоже идея...

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Перечислю все известные мне способы идентификации пользователя.

### IP-адрес

Указываю этот способ потому, что он единственный, который невозможно подделать. Его можно позаимствовать у других (прокси, VPN, Tor, просто динамический IP), но это обычно сложнее, чем, например, почистить куки. Удалить IP-адрес, аналогично чистке cookies, нельзя: какой-нибудь обязательно будет. В связи с его относительной надёжностью (не всем не лень держать наготове сотни прокси-серверов для смены IP) его часто используют для усиления безопасности: например, ограничивают максимальное число запросов в секунду/минуту/час с одного IP. Однако разных людей, сидящих через один интернет, IP различить не даст, что противоречит условию вопроса, поэтому едем дальше.

### Банальные логин и пароль

Суть проста: тупо шлём логин и пароль в каждом запросе. Один из вариантов реализации этого способа уже присутствует в самом протоколе HTTP, через заголовок `Authorization`, уже реализован во всех основных веб-браузерах и веб-серверах.

В HTTP-варианте суть такова:

- при первом посещении сайта у клиента ничего нет и никакой дополнительной информации серверу не шлёт. Сервер отвечает ошибкой `401 Unauthorized` и добавляет HTTP-заголовок `WWW-Authenticate` с информацией о способах входа (для простого логина-пароля это `Basic realm="default"`)
- клиент получает это всё и просит у пользователя логин и пароль. После чего отправляет свой запрос повторно, но уже с HTTP-заголовком `Authorization`, в котором содержится логин-пароль в base64: `Basic YWRtaW46MTIzNDU2`. Если этот пример раскодировать, получим `admin:123456` — логин и пароль, разделённые двоеточием
- сайт это всё проверяет и или отвечает нормально, или опять 401 и запрашиваем логин-пароль на новый
- Этот `Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46MTIzNDU2` шлём каждый раз во всех последующих запросах.

Достоинства:

- простота. HTTP Basic Auth уже реализован в большинстве веб-браузеров и веб-серверов, ничего изобретать не надо. Если делать свой вариант, то достаточно реализовать проверку логина-пароля в каждом запросе без дополнительных сложностей.

Проблемы:

- без HTTPS безопасность вообще никакая: логин-пароль по сути ходят по интернету в открытом виде (base64 не является шифрованием). Клиент тоже вынужден помнить у себя пароль в открытом виде, да и сервер тоже знает пароль (существуют схемы аутентификации, при которых сервер может и не знать пароль, но вопрос не об этом);
- HTTP Basic Auth в браузерах работает только в пределах текущей сессии; после перезапуска браузера логин-пароль нужно вводить снова.

Справедливости ради отмечу, что HTTP умеет не только голые логин-пароль ([возможно полный список спосбов авторизации](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-authschemes/http-authschemes.xhtml)), но останавливаться на других способах не буду в связи с их низкой распространённостью.

### Случайная строка

Самый простой, самый сбалансированный в отношении «безопасность/удобство» и самый популярный способ идентификации. Самая распространённая в мире (наверно) кука PHPSESSID — это именно оно. Суть такова:

- при первом посещении сайта у клиента ничего нет. Сайт замечает это, создаёт новую случайную строку (подлиннее, чтоб трудно было подобрать; символов 30 хотя бы) и вместе с обычным ответом на запрос тем или иным образом отправляет эту сгенерированную строку (Set-Cookie, редирект на специальную ссылку или просто в теле ответа, если это например JSON API)
- клиент вместе с ответом получает эту строку и запоминает её где-нибудь (браузер сам хранит в cookies, SPA может положить её в localStorage и т.п.)
- при последующих посещениях сайта клиент добавляет эту строку к своему запросу (cookies, HTTP-заголовок Authentication или просто GET-параметр в запрашиваемом адресе — на некоторых старых PHP-форумах до сих пор можно наблюдать id сессии прямо в адресной строке)
- если нужно идентифицировать клиента более конкретно (вход по логину-паролю, например), сайт в своей базе данных после записывает, что такой-то случайной строке соответствует такой-то логин, а потом при последующих запросах считывает эту информацию из базы.

Если говорить о PHP, то всё это в него встроено: при вызове функции `session_start()` создаётся кука `PHPSESSID` из случайных букв и цифр (или читается существующая, если она уже есть). Данные, которые связаны с этой кукой, доступны через массив `$_SESSION` (а физически хранятся по умолчанию где-то в специальном каталоге на сервере), и вы можете его читать и изменять. При последующих запросах от пользователя содержимое сессии автоматически прочитается из файла при вызове `session_start()`, и все данные, которые вы положили в массив `$_SESSION` при обработке предыдущих запросов, снова станут доступны. Подробности в [документации](https://secure.php.net/manual/ru/session.examples.basic.php).

Достоинства:

- простота — сравнивать строки тривиально;
- при смене IP-адреса (а на мобильниках это частое явление) идентификация не слетает;
- реализация кнопочки «Разлогинить меня на всех устройствах» сводится к простому удалению всех записей в базе, а если для каждого устройства создавать отдельную строку, то можно разлогинивать устройства выборочно (некоторые сайты предоставляют такую возможность, например ВК).

Проблемы:

- генератор случайной строки должен быть действительно случайным (или [не совсем случайным, но криптостойким](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_%D0%BF%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB), не `uniqid()`), так как псевдослучайность злоумышленник может попытаться подобрать (например, подбор состояния генератора в [PHP](https://habr.com/ru/company/pt/blog/149746/) или [Python](https://habr.com/ru/company/pt/blog/156133/), или [подбор сессий, созданных черех uniqid(), в Invision Power Board](https://medium.com/@iancarroll/bypassing-authentication-in-invision-power-board-with-cve-2016-2564-9a24ea3655f9)). Ни в коем случае в качестве строки нельзя использовать хэш логина, хэш пароля, текущее время, одну-единственную заранее заготовленную строку и прочие неслучайные вещи, так как это сильно упрощает подбор. Как получить настоящую случайность, читайте в документации к вашему языку программирования. Или просто используйте готовую реализацию вроде `session_start()` в PHP;
- дополнительная нагрузка на сервер. Чтобы узнать, какой именно пользователь прячется за случайной строкой, ему приходится обращаться к базе данных. Не проблема для подавляющего большинства сайтов, но для гигантов типа гугла уже проблема;
- куки иногда баганутые: например, IE11 [добавляет куки к поддоменам, даже когда его не просят](http://inikulin.github.io/cookie-compat/#DOMAIN0029) (в Edge уже исправлено), что может привести к утечке данных на сторонние CDN, например. Поэтому следите за тем, как браузеры, для которых вы затачиваете сайт, манипулируют с куками. Ну и про HttpOnly не забывайте, чтобы нельзя было угнать куки через XSS (и про Secure, если сайт использует HTTPS).

### Неслучайная, но защищённая строка (например, JWT)

Суть такова: нагло нарушаем вышеупомянутый запрет на неслучайные данные и пихаем в строку, например, ID пользователя и, опционально, имеющиеся права доступа (например, админ ли он), срок годности строки и какие-нибудь ещё данные. Но! Дополнительно к этой строке добавляем какой-нибудь хэш, который считается по данным плюс некой секретной строке, которую знает только сайт и никому не отдаёт. При запросе от клиента сайт, соответственно, проверяет, что хэш правильный. Это защищает от подбора и подделок: чтобы подделать данные, нужно пересчитать хэш, а злоумышленник, не зная секретной строки, этого сделать не сможет. (Секретная строка должна быть ОЧЕНЬ длинной, символов сто, чтоб вообще не подобрать, так как на ней вся безопасность.) (В JWT также вместо просто секретной строки можно применять RSA для подписи, что повышает безопасность, но расписывать все детали реализации не буду, и так длинно получилось)

Достоинства:

- меньшая нагрузка на сервер. Клиент уже сам прислал все нужные данные, серверу остаётся лишь посчитать хэш от этих данных и секретной строки и проверить, что он совпадает с присланным. В базу данных ходить не надо: секретная строка обычно лежит в какой-нибудь переменной поблизости, так что всё это делается быстро;
- независимость от централизованной базы данных позволяет легко проверять аутентификацию на независимых и никак не связанных друг с другом микросервисах, в том числе географически разбросанных по миру, ведь им достаточно знать лишь секретную строку, которая меняется очень редко, для проверки присланного пользователем хэша, и не нужно связываться с другими микросервисами или с базой;
- клиент сам может прочитать JWT и понять, кто он такой (если данные только защищать хэшем, а не шифровать);
- при смене IP-адреса тоже не слетает.

Проблемы:

- реализация усложняется. Если делать всё самому, то можно накосячить и получить дырку в безопасности, поэтому лучше брать готовые реализации вроде того же JWT (впрочем, в них тоже иногда находят дырки, так что обязательно мониторим новости и почитываем Хабр);
- кнопочку «Разлогинить меня на всех устройствах» сделать вообще нельзя. Чтобы пользовательская строка с данными стала недействительной, нужно или сменить секретную строку, или запомнить где-то в базе, что именно такая-то строка с такими-то данными стала недействительна. Но это всё довольно проблематично и сводит на нет все преимущества данного способа идентификации. Поэтому такие строки, как правило, делают короткоживущими: например, Google в своих API выдаёт JWT, действительный всего полчаса (информация о сроке годности хранится прямо в JWT и тоже защищается хэшем, в базу ходить не надо).
- информация может протухнуть. Например, если записать в JWT, что пользователь является админом, а потом отобрать права админа, то сайт, опираясь на данные JWT, будет продолжать считать клиента админом, пока сам JWT не протухнет целиком. Можно брать информацию из базы, но тогда опять становится проще использовать случайную строку.
- JWT и аналоги из-за того, что содержат всю необходимую информацию, обычно длинные; при большом количестве данных строка может, например, не влезть в cookies. Впрочем, если хранить только id пользователя, то это не проблема.

### Суперкуки и прочий фингерпринтинг

Суть в использовании технологий не по назначению. У каждого браузера и каждой ОС есть свои особенности поведения, и по этим особенностям можно довольно точно идентифицировать, кто именно зашёл. Например, они рисуют текст немного по-разному, и по мелким отличиям в пикселях текста браузеры можно различать, или же на разных компьютерах будет немножко разный размер окна браузера, развёрнутого на весь экран (поэтому Tor Browser рекомендует не разворачивать его и блокирует сайтам доступ к canvas). Не буду расписывать всё во всех подробностях, оставлю ссылки для дальнейшего чтения:

- [Evercookie — самые устойчивые куки](https://habr.com/ru/post/104725/)
- [Panopticlick 2.0 для фингерпринтинга браузера](https://habr.com/ru/post/356958/)
- [Супер-куки на основе HSTS отследят вас даже в приватном режиме](https://habr.com/ru/post/252433/)

Достоинства:

- хрен выпилишь. Если захотеть, то можно, конечно, но уж очень много мороки: нужно уметь мимикрировать под популярное сочетание браузер/ОС/устройство, чтобы «смешаться с серой массой». Это уже не просто кнопочку «Очистить cookies» нажать. Без специальных мер устройство клиента будет идентифицировано независимо от того, сменил ли он IP-адрес, почистил ли куки и т.п.

Проблемы:

- точность не стопроцентная. Все айфоны довольно одинаковые, и отличить один айфон X от другого айфона X вряд ли получится (хотя это касается только фингерпринтинга, для суперкук попроще);
- пользователи вас найдут и больно побьют.

Comment: Ты, большая умница, еще раз благодарю, картину прояснил больше чем я ожидал...  Не скажу, что я не абсолютный чайник, понимания самой логики программирования, вот то, что читаю в твоем ответе, оказалось знаю, не все, но большее, но знал поверхностно, а сейчас знаю намного глубже...

Comment: Добавил про проблемы с кешем в связи с куками, если вы не против.

Comment: Поправка: настоящая случайность не обязательна, хватит и псевдослучайности - главное чтобы ГСЧ был криптостойким.

Comment: @sanmai откатил ваши правки, противоречащие стандартам и опровергающиеся простыми экспериментами

Comment: @PavelMayorov упомянул его в скобочках

Comment: @andreymal каким стандартам, простите? Кеширование запросов с заголовком `Set-Cookie` противоречит просто здравому смыслу.

Comment: @sanmai кратко: Set-Cookie используется ровно один раз при установке куки (второго раза может вообще не наступить, если кука долгоживущая), поэтому проблемы с ним — не проблемы. Согласно RFC 6265 куки по умолчанию распространяются только на текущий домен, а для поддоменов типа CDN нужно явно прописать опцию domain. JWT обычно добавляется только джаваскриптом и не через куки, поэтому при скачивании статики JWT не передаётся и проблемы опять же не существует. Откатил ваши правки второй раз, если вы хотите возразить, лучше сделать это в каком-нибудь чате, а не войной правок.

Comment: @andreymal Давайте сначала обсудим, а потом вы будете откатывать. Вот вы упоминаете RFC 6265. Сколько браузеров его поддерживают?

Comment: @sanmai давайте сначала обсудим, а потом вы будете накатывать. Сколько браузеров нарушают упомянутую мной вещь, прописанную в RFC 6265?

Comment: @sanmai про случайность тоже написали всё кривее и я тоже вынужден откатить ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @andreymal [большинство браузеров не поддерживают RFC 6265 в части кук, поставленных на домене второго уровня](http://inikulin.github.io/cookie-compat/#DOMAIN0029); Верните мои правки, пожалуйста. А хотя нет, не возвращайте. Я свой ответ напишу.

Comment: @sanmai «all cookies are set on home.example.org and results are inspected on home.example.org», так что эти тесты никак не влияют на (не)правильность ваших правок.

Comment: ...except for those tests where the results URL is explicitly specified... и там `Results URL: http://subdomain.home.example.org:...` - посмотрите внимательней, там именно этот вариант с доменом на уровень ниже проверяется

Comment: @sanmai проглядел, но вы же сами прекрасно видите, что это баг в одном лишь IE. Пишите багрепорт, а не правку (а правкой добавьте уже ссылку на ваш багрепорт)

Comment: Ну то есть если куки пользователя, зашедшего под "одном лишь IE", утекут куда-то на субдомен в CDN, то это нормально и хорошо, так? Ваш ответ я править не буду, так - чисто понять вашу позицию.

Comment: @sanmai на свой CDN - ничего плохого, кроме, может, крохотно замедления. Опять же, спрашивайте это у разработчиков IE/Edge, а не у меня - в доминирующих Chrome и Firefox всё (в контексте обсуждаемых правок) работает нормально.

Comment: Понятно. Получается так что если кто следует вашим рекомендациям, то они игнорируют интересы 4% своих пользователей. Свой CDN - о чём вы, это вообще не для средних сайтов, обычно CDN это Amazon CloudFront и подобные. Даже [у этого сайта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/) нет своей CDN, а используется Fastly.

Comment: @sanmai кроме того, похоже, в Edge баг уже исправлен, так как воспроизвести эту проблему с куками и поддоменом в свежеобновлённой Windows 10 мне не удалось (в IE11 воспроизводится, но баги IE11 — проблемы пользователей IE11). Так что ваши правки не нужны)

Comment: Вы не правы. Если у вас интернет-банк или другой серьёзный сайт, то баги с куками IE11 - это ваши проблемы. Вы не можете от них отмахнуться. Даже Яндекс не может, хотя он не банк.

Comment: @sanmai банку, использующему не свой CDN, я бы точно не доверял :)

Comment: Давайте ваш банк, я скажу своя у него CDN или нет. У моего банка, например, Akamai используется. Но эти очень серьёзные и дорогие ребята.

Comment: @sanmai про полную небезопасность Сбербанка писали уже все кому не лень, вы мне ничего нового не расскажете :D

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75486/discussion-between-sanmai-and-andreymal).

Comment: Я даже забыл, что награждать можно сразу))))))  Спасибо еще раз...

Comment: Кстати, там сейчас поднимают панику по поводу возможности трекинга используя TLS сессию. Браузеры из анонимных вкладок используют сессии из обычных вкладок. Это проблема очень старая, но почему-то паника поднимается именно сейчас.

Answer (score 9):

В дополнение к [сказанному о недостатках кук](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/739736/201364) можно сказать что:

- Прозрачный серверный кеш запросов становится невозможен если используются куки (будь это Varnish или [прозрачное кеширование в nginx](https://habrahabr.ru/post/124684/)). Потому если не ставить куки со стороны сервера, если они не нужны, то страницы сайта смогут использовать серверный кеш и будут открываться быстрее. Попытки кешировать запросы с заголовком `Set-Cookie` противоречат просто здравому смыслу, значит они тоже проходят мимо кеша.
- Настройка CDN для статических ресурсов требует внимания если используются куки. Если ваш сайт открывается без `www` по адресу, например, `test.ru`, то, поставив куку на сайте, можно будет считать что эта кука будет передаваться в запросах ко всем поддоменам, включая, например, `cdn.test.ru`. Потому на сайтах, которые традиционно открываются без `www`, вы можете видеть что для статических ресурсов используется отдельный домен второго уровня, а не поддомен. Например `yastatic.net` у Яндекса.

  Последнюю проблему должен был исправить RFC 6265, но на момент написания этого ответа некоторые основные браузеры [всё ещё не поддерживают его в полней мере](http://inikulin.github.io/cookie-compat/). От этих старых браузеров всё ещё нельзя просто так отмахнуться, так как не во всём мире использование старых браузеров одинаково низко: например, в Японии на март 2018 года [IE используется для 16% всех запросов](http://gs.statcounter.com/browser-market-share/all/japan/#monthly-201803-201803-bar). А это страна в которой живёт 127 миллионов человек. Если вы делаете глобальный сервис, то так и так вам придётся действовать будто RFC 6265 ещё нет.

Кроме JWT можно вспомнить другие "длинные" куки [вроде ViewState из ASP.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668225.aspx#Anchor_1), которым свойственны те же проблемы с кешированием и CDN, что и со обычными сессионными случайными куками, только хуже. Такие и подобные куки могут быть очень большие, запросто по десятку килобайт, а если они будут передаваться с каждым запросом к любой картинке или статическому файлу на вашем сайте, то это будет определённо сказываться на скорости работы сайта во всех режимах. Майкрософт прямо рекомендуют не пользоваться ими если вам важна скорость сайта.

#### Что ещё?

Вместо кук можно использовать всевозможные заголовки, которые могут попасть в браузерный кеш. Например, если вы однажды послали с какой-то картинкой или файлом заголовок ETag, то при следующем обращении браузер [снова перешлёт значение этого заголовка](https://habrahabr.ru/post/126643/). Пользователю никак не видно что вы его так отслеживаете, то есть знаете, что это вот тот человек зашел ещё раз, потому такие приёмы не приветствуются.

#### Итого

Если вы можете *не* идентифицировать ваших пользователей, то ваш сайт сможет работать быстрее.

Comment: Серверный кеш надо ставить после модуля авторизации, а не перед ним. В случае использования кеша на обратном прокси прокси также можно настроить чтобы он куку не трогал. А вообще, страницы нужно разделять на те где содержимое одинаково для всех пользователей и те где содержимое отличается. Первым кука не нужна по определению, вторые нельзя кешировать на сервере также по определению.

Comment: Благодарю, Господа, и ответ и комментарий вполне содержательны...

Comment: @PavelMayorov как это вы поставите nginx *после* модуля авторизации? Какого модуля? Какие директивы при этом будете использовать? Давайте подробности.

Comment: @sanmai не придуривайтесь. Вариант с nginx я описал в следующем предложении.

Comment: «поставив куку на сайте, эта же кука по умолчанию будет передаваться в запросах ко всем поддоменам» — уберите это враньё пожалуйста, вы же сами видели, что эта проблема существует только в IE

Comment: Нет, не буду убирать. Это очень важно если вам важны пользователи IE, а эти пользователи могу в денежном выражении давать десяток процентов оборота в каком-нибудь интернет-магазине.

Comment: @sanmai проблема двух процентов пользователей ну никак не тянут «по умолчанию». Когда у RFC и 98% посетителей поведение отличается от вашего «по умолчанию» — это враньё. Ловите минус в таком случае.

Comment: @andreymal окей, как насчёт [16% японцев, которые всё ещё пользуются IE](http://gs.statcounter.com/browser-market-share/all/japan/#monthly-201803-201803-bar)? Это 21 миллион человек, между прочим. Есть и другие страны, в которых похожая ситуация.

Comment: @PavelMayorov в каком предложении? Вы вообще исходный вопрос читали? К чему ваши негодующие комментарии?

Comment: @sanmai то, что у 106 миллионов человек в Японии поведение не «по умолчанию» — это ничего? Тогда я точно так же заявляю, что на компьютерах людей по всему миру «по умолчанию» стоит линукс — целых несколько процентов как-никак.

Comment: Хотя фраза «по умолчанию» из ответа пропала, ну хоть что-то.

Answer (score 8):

Как правило используются `Cookies` - определенная строка данных, которая хранится у пользователя в браузере. Алгоритм их генерации вы можете сделать сами, либо использовать родной движка, например `PHPSESSID` в `PHP` (смотри функцию `session_start()`).

Можно так же идентифицировать пользователя без них, но в данном случае необходимо будет использовать другие параметры, к которым есть доступ.
Это, в первую очередь User-agent (браузер пользователя) и его IP адрес. В случае `PHP` эти переменные хранятся в `$_SERVER`:

`1. $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`
 `2. $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`

Соответственно, второй вариант обладает меньшей точностью, но будет работать, если у пользователя отключено хранение `Cookie`. Пример ошибки во втором случае - два пользователя находятся за NAT и используют одинаковый браузер.