# Сессия или Куки?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, form

Добрый день, появилась задача сделать одноразовую форму обратной связи, и я не могу решить, что лучше использовать кукки или сессию, для проверки первого посещения юзера.

Сайт на wp, кстати буду благодарен так же если подскажите какой-то толковый мануал по работе с формами в wp, а то меня чуток смущает тот факт что скрипт который обрабатывает мою форму находится сразу во вью, данные туда отправляю ajaxом. 
Спасибо большое!

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Что именно идентифицирует посетителя сайта?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/739684)

Answer (score 0):

Как правило, идентификатор сессии у пользователя хранится в Cookie, поэтому "использовать сессию или куки" - фактически одно и тоже.

Нужно создать action в function.php (или создать отдельный файл типо actions.php), ajax-ом отправлять туда форму и уже в нем обрабатывать.

[Ajax в Wordpress](https://wp-kama.ru/id_2018/ajax-v-wordpress.html)

Comment: Я имею в ввиду лучше использовать просто куки которые потом заносить в БД или достаточно будет пользовать сессию?

Comment: @AntonKolesnikov, я думаю, что сессии достаточно. Если не ошибаюсь, то сессионая кука имеет lifetime = 0, т.е. живет до закрытия браузера. Думаю этого вполне достаточно, ибо если пользователь поставит себе цель заполнить форму два раза, он это сделает без особых проблем (инкогнито в браузере и т.д.).