# Как можно "запомнить" пользователя

Tags: php, html, mysql

Мне нужно что бы сайт запомнил логин и пароль пользователя, как это реализовать? Думаю, можно ввести в базу данных его ip и первичный ключ, но не слишком ли это примитивно? Я к тому, что если ip у пользователя не статический - то сайт просто не сможет его запомнить, ТК ip будет постоянно новый, по моему запоминать  данные таким образом - костыль или все же сойдёт? Извиняюсь за довольно абстрактный вопрос, но более точно сформулировать его не могу.

Comment: Тебе нужно использовать сессии. Это такой механизм, когда ты присваиваешь некий идентификатор пользователю, и кладешь это значение ему в куку session. При этом, при каждом обращении пользователя на твой сайт, ты по содержимому этой куки сможешь сопоставить пришедшего человека, с уникальным пользователем. Подробнее можешь прочесть вот тут: http://komotoz.ru/uroki/php/sessii_v_php.php

Comment: Возможно, речь о [«Что именно идентифицирует посетителя сайта?»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/739684)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Стандартно для таких вещей используют куки и сессии, если Вы имеете ввиду (под запомнить пользователя), автоматическую авторизацию при повторном посещении сайта, (если к примеру пользователь установил чекбокс "Запомнить меня"), тогда при регистрации пользователя пишете в базу его логин и хеш пароля, созданного к примеру при помощи [password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.password-hash.php), затем при авторизации проверяете совпадает ли введенный пароль с хешем в БД, при помощи [password_verify()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.password-verify.php), затем если пользователь установил чекбокс "Запомнить меня", создаете cookie и как вариант можно записать логин и хеш в зашифрованном виде, затем уже доставать эти данные и подставлять для авторизации. А что по поводу IP так это действительно бесполезно, так как ~80%, динамические, и будут меняться почти при каждом переподключении к сети. В сети очень много информации о методах авторизации, и [cookies](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.setcookie.php).