# NodeJs. Работа с сессиями без использования Express

Tags: node.js, сессия, авторизация

Добрый день! Решил сделать на сайте авторизацию.  Навыков, чтобы сделать подобное, нет. Я так понял, что изучение необходимо начать над работой с сессиями. Гугл наводнен примерами и обучающими материалами о работе с сессиями в связке с Express. Однако, у меня сайт написан без использования этого фреймворка. Кто может подсказать учебный материал по интересующей меня проблеме? Подойдет все: книги, видео, посты, блоги...

Comment: Главное - понять принцип работы сессии. Можно реализовать и самому. В случае сайта, при авторизации клиенту дается "ключ", который записывается в куки (на сервере этот ключ сохраняется + сохраняется информация о пользователе). При каждом запросе на сервер по ключу ищется пользователь и, если находит, то использует информацию, сохраненную при авторизации. Информацию о сессии можно хранить в оперативной памяти, бд, жестком диске..

Comment: Согласен. Но с максимально приблеженными примерами оно лучше понимается)

Comment: @Дмытрык, почитай, может найдешь для себя чего-то полезного...
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/739684/Что-именно-идентифицирует-посетителя-сайта

Comment: @Air, благодарю. Ответ там шикарен

Comment: @Дмытрык, рад был помочь...