# Система лайков без авторизации

Tags: php

Всем привет! Есть задача, сделать кнопку "Мне нравится" под статьёй. Но проблема в том, что на сайте нет авторизации для пользователей, как быть в этом случае? Я думал сделать с помощью сессий, верное ли это решение? Или стоит использовать какой либо другой способ? И если все же делать с помощью сессий то как это организовать? Создать сессию и указать ей большой период времени? В интернете находил только статьи с авторизацией, если у кого нибудь есть пример без авторизации прошу поделится)

Comment: Толку ноль, убить сессию через браузер не проблема и накрутить +100500 лайков, тоже не проблема. Без авторизаций - делать бессмысленно. Накрутка неизбежна. За частую, даже и с авторизацией, можно накрутить. Разными аккаунтами.

Comment: `"Мне нравиться"` ваш вопрос. Все легко, задача стоит так: как идентифицировать клиента, без авторизации. Самый простой способ - используя его IP, офк это не гарантирует 100% защиты, те у кого динамический смогут накручивать, но мы тут и не говорим о 100% защите. + к IP, можно добавить куки, недели достаточно, максимум месяц. От хацкеров не спасет, но для рядовых пользователей - достаточно.

Comment: Такой вопрос был уже. Почитайте [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/739684/Что-именно-идентифицирует-посетителя-сайта)