# Vue JS безопасность, подмена данных возможна?

Tags: vue.js, безопасность

в меру свой упорности и попыток защитить данные, стоит вопрос о подмене данных. Использую VueJS на сайте, есть переменные, различного типа. К примеру после авторизации пользователя, я получаю с `store` переменную `user.lvl` понятно что это уровень пользователя и от этого зависит какие данные отображать какие нет, тоже касается `id` итп. Стоит вопрос, я сам подменить у себя не смог, но возможно ли подменить их в браузере или телефоне через js к примеру? Я могу легко менять данные самого app или компонентов (на локальном сервере)  но к стору доступ не получили, даже в `DevTools`.

Я не смог отследить у себя данные, помимо тех что приходят по ajax запросу, но тут я их просто вижу, вопрос именно подмены штатным методом.

Волнует доступ к закрытым разделам сайта после подмены или при подмене id пользователя доступ к личным данным.

Comment: Небольшой намёк: пользователь может хоть напрограммировать себе свой собственный браузер с какими угодно возможностями в нём

Comment: @andreymal  не понял намека :) Я понимаю, что он может делать что хочет. Но я то не хочу чтобы при подмене id показали ему после запроса на сервер того чего не нужно )

Comment: @RuslanSemenov если вы боитесь того, что на сервер отправится запрос с «неправильным» id — так браузер и vue здесь вообще ни при чём: я могу просто написать скрипт в десяток строчек на том же nodejs, который будет отправлять какие угодно запросы куда угодно по моему хотению. Защита должна быть на сервере, а не в браузере и не в vue. Да и в браузерах редактирование запросов тоже есть

Comment: Да, я согласен. Но приложение уже крутится на стороне клиента и если у меня проверка `v-if="user.lvl > 2"` то я подменив 1 на 99 получу все? Так же стор в зависимости от каких либо данных отвечает isAdmin true/false

Comment: @RuslanSemenov эта проверка просто должна быть на сервере. Даже если юзер подменит 1 на 99 у себя, то пусть он даже увидит все опасные кнопочки — они просто будут неработоспособны, потому что проверка на сервере должна выпнуть такого пользователя с ошибкой доступа

Comment: хм... идея понятно, вернулся к защите api, не хотел напрягать при каждом запросе проверять юзера, или добавлять в запрос еще одно условие.

Comment: Ну и да, сервер не должен присылать в этот ваш стор никаких секретных данных, если у пользователя нет доступа — тогда будет просто нечего показывать, даже если пользователь заменит 1 на 99. Ну и да, сама проверка пользователя на сервере должна быть надёжной, потому что если, к примеру, он будет идентифицироваться просто по числовому id, то можно было бы просто подменить свой id на id админа, чтобы получить все доступы — см. [Что именно идентифицирует посетителя сайта?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/739684)

Comment: Кстати, иногда бывают сайты с кривой идентификацией пользователя по IP-адресу — на таких бывает достаточно добавить HTTP-заголовок `X-Forwarded-For: 127.0.0.1`, чтобы получить все права админа (хотя я очень надеюсь, что таких сайтов в 2018 году уже не существует)

Comment: Спасибо за все ссылки, почитаю и это. К сожалению пока не нашел для себя решения правильно защиты, все сам себя ломаю и латать приходится постоянно.