# Что хранить в куки после авторизации

Tags: php, регистрация

Какие данные записывать в куки после авторизации? Пароль, полагаю, хранить небезопасно, но какой идентификатор можно использовать, чтобы определять юзера?

Comment: Например айди сессии с неким хэшем =) хэш логин + пароль... много чего можно хранить, главное чтобы эти данные не давали возможности получить исходный пароль.

Comment: Чем стандартный механизм сессий не устроил ? Зачем вообще пароль в куки сунуть ?

Comment: Признаюсь, когда-то тоже этим грешил... Сунул в Куку логин пользователя, шифровал хешем от IP, Юзерагента и текущей даты. Агоритм шифрования был самодельным, посути - шифр замены по таблице хешей этих же символов... Еще та адская смесь. !!!НЕ ПОВТОРЯЙТЕ ЭТОГО ДОМА!!!

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что именно идентифицирует посетителя сайта?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/739684/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%84%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b0)

Comment: (дописал туда ↑ абзац конкретно про php)

Answer (score 0):

Используй [сессию](http://php.net/manual/ru/session.examples.basic.php). Тогда в клиетна будет только радномно сгенерированая строка, а все данные будут на сервере. И туда можете пихать уже все что угодно - логин, пароль, ID юзера, какие-то настройки... Да всё что душа пожелает)

Comment: Но сессия действительна только 15 минут, а мне нужно долгосрочное хранение.

Comment: Сессия не 15 минут, а до закрытия страницы) Если нужно долгосрочное хранение - лучше сохраняйте в базу с привязкой до ID юзера. Тогда даже если юзер выйдет, потом, когда снова залогинится, получит данные)