# Post и Get запросы. Node js

Tags: node.js, post, get, express

Делаю вход к себе на сайт. Использую Node.js + Express
В POST запросе обрабатываю логин и пароль и вывожу нужную страницу. После захода на страницу появляется нужная мне информация, но при обновлении страницы GET не видет (не понимает) этой информации и не рендерит страницу.

Как сделать так,чтобы GET обновлял страницу с нужной информацией ?

**Обнова** (мой код, с которым я работаю)

**Основной файл index.js**

```
const express = require ("express")
const app = express ()
const pg = require("pg")
app.use(express.static("public"))
app.set("views","./views")
app.listen(4000)
app.set('view engine','ejs')

vhod = require("./postgresRole")   // файл где беру инф какой пользователь
const bodyParser= require('body-parser')
const urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false});

app.post("/inside_class",urlencodedParser,function(req,res) {
vhod1 = new vhod()
vhod1.searchUser(req,res)
})

app.get("/inside_class",urlencodedParser,function(req,res) {
res.render('inside_class')
})
```

**Файл postgresRole.js**

```
const pg = require("pg")
sotr = require("./sotrRole") 
class PostgresRole {
    constructor() {

        this.config = {
            user:'login',
            database:'school',
            password:'123',
            host:'localhost',
            port:5432,
            max:10,
            idleTimeoutMillis: 30000
        }
        console.log("конструктор")
    }
searchUser(req, res) {
        var pool = new pg.Pool(this.config)
        pool.connect(function(err, client, done){
            //return_data = {}
            if(err){
                return console.error('Соединение не удалось')
            }

            client.query('SELECT * FROM log_view WHERE id_pupil = $1 AND pass = $2',[req.body.login, req.body.password], function(err, result){
                done()
                //return_data.log =result
                if (err || result.rowCount <= 0){
                    res.end()
                    return console.error("Запрос не удался")
                }
                if(result.rows[0].name === "Ученик")
                {
                        pool.end()
                        client.end()
                        sotr = new sotr()
                        sotr.getClients(res)
                        console.log("Вошел как ученик")
                }
}
module.exports = PostgresRole
```

**Файл sotrRole.js**

```
const pg = require("pg")

class EmployeeRole {
    constructor() {
        this.config = {
            user:'pupil1',
            database:'school',
            password:'1111',
            host:'localhost',
            port:5432,
            max:10,
            idleTimeoutMillis: 30000
        }
        console.log("Вошли в ученика")
    }

    getClients(res){

        var pool = new pg.Pool(this.config)

            pool.connect(function(err, client, done) {
                if(err){
                    return console.error('Соединение не удалось')
                }
                //return_data = {}
                client.query('SELECT * FROM pupil where id_pupil=4', function(err, result){
                    done()
                    //return_data.pupil =result
                    if (err) {
                        res.end()
                        return console.error("Запрос не удался")
                    }

                    res.render('inside_class', {pupil2:result})

                    console.log("Зашло в запрос")
                })
                console.log("Вошли в Postgres")
            })
     }
}
module.exports = EmployeeRole
```

Comment: а как GET узнает, что Вы зарегистрированный пользователь?

Comment: @Дмытрык  В этом и проблема, я не знаю как сделать так,чтобы GET это как-то узнал.

Comment: Сессии, куки, специальный заголовок с токеном...

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/739684/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0

Comment: если говоря коротко, в момент авторизации необходимо клиенту передать какую-нибудь метку, которую он будет отправлять при каждом последующем запросе. На сервере Вы должны сравнить эту метку с существующими и определить, что делать дальше

Comment: @Дмытрык А, есть какой-то пример ? Чтобы я мог сориентироваться. Буду очень признателен.

Comment: Это много кода, + я не использую express, + использую БД, Вам будет проще понять суть и написать самому. Там нет ничего сложного. Вы же про кукисы слышали? https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookies

Comment: @Дмытрык С эти еще не работал.... Я, работаю тоже с БД - PostgreSQL. Добавил сверху мои файлы с которым работаю. Может подскажите,что нужно изменить или добавить.

Answer (score 0):

Так как это уже клиентская обработка(второй запрос get на странице или какие-либо другие действия после первичного рендера) вам поможет [AJAX](https://habr.com/ru/post/14246/), или опять посылать на эту же страницу ваши основные данные, а именно логин и пароль, тогда все отрендерится.